# Editing Date and Time Separately in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, time, binding

I have a class for Timesheet records called Time. This class includes fields for the employees pin, in punch, out punch ect. I have a collection of these Times that are bound to a DataGrid.

My goal is to be able to edit just the time component of a punch. Every once and while the date component will need to be adjusted as well though. What would be the best approach for this?

My Current XAML

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="In Day">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path = In, StringFormat = '{}{0:ddd}'}"  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <DatePicker x:Name="datePicker" SelectedDate="{Binding Path = In}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="In">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path = In, StringFormat= '{}{0:hh:mm tt}'}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <telerik:RadTimePicker SelectedValue="{Binding Path = In}" TimeInterval="0:15:0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

My issue with this is that when I pick a Date in the DatePicker it sets my Time to 12:00 AM.

Whats the best method for doing this? Do I need to store Date and Time in separate fields? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Put your DateTime in a bound hidden column.  Put a copy of the date in an editable column, put the editable time in another column.  When one of the editable columns is updated, you will need to update your hidden column so that the value is correct - Date + Time.

Answer (score 0):

Store date and time separately is a good idea. In your ViewModel, keep two DateTime properties, one for date and one for time, both with Changed notification. Bind them to your date and time column, and in their set accessors, modify a third DateTime property, which is your final value, respectively.